# Windows mobile exception handling

Tags: windows-mobile

Is there a way in Windows Mobile to catch global unhandled exceptions?  If not, are there any workarounds?  Specifically, we have a thin client app and we want to globally catch exceptions generated when the network is unavailable (so we can present a friendly message and prompt the user to try again).

This catch statement **doesn't** fire when I throw an exception on button press

```
 try
 {
   Application.Run(new Login());
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
   Debug.WriteLine("Caught " + ex);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [AppDomain.UnhandledException handler](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/appdomainunhandledexception-part-1.aspx), but you cannot recover from it - you can only log it and shutdown the app.  There's no way to have a global handler that is recoverable (at least in the CF) because there's no way to guarantee app state at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static void Main(), and add a try/catch that surround everything in the method body.

Comment: I had already tried that - see edits to original question - and it wasn't catching the error.